# linux red-hat 7.1 + increase the ring buffer

Tags: linux, networking, framebuffer, ifconfig

My target is to increase the ring buffer ( I have Linux red-hat 7.1 ) , but I get the following:

```
ethtool -G eth1 rx 8192
Cannot set device ring parameters: Invalid argument
```

so how to enable this value? , or maybe this is the MAX value?

the current status:

```
ethtool -g eth1
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:             256
RX Mini:        0
RX Jumbo:       0
TX:             512
```

I want to increase the ring buffer because errors - pkts rx OOB - indicate that the network card is out of buffer

Comment: Maybe try this: ethtool -G eth1 rx-jumbo 8192 and see if it works?  Also, maybe this will help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Jumbo_frames

Comment: hi Vil , see please the link - http://serverfault.com/questions/762666/redhat-7-1-increase-nic-ring-buffer   , they are almost sure about the MAX value , but I will try your solution ....

Comment: I will happy to hear from you remarks if you have -:)